# Pandas игнорирует разделитель в CSV файле с излишним обрамляющим квотированием

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Есть самый просто csv файл с такими данными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я в jupyter notebook пытаюсь загрузить его в pandas:

```
import pandas as pd       
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
```

То получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выходит получить нормальный вид ни с одним из известных мне разделителей.

Пробовал с другими файлами, все работает отлично.

В чём может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста?

UPD файл в блокноте выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте csv-файл в блокноте и покажите нам его содержимое простым текстом, а не скриншотом из Excel

Comment: Ну вот, видимые в блокноте кавычки намекают, что у вас файле ровно один столбец, содержащий строки с запятыми, и pandas открывает всё абсолютно правильно

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно ли из этого получить нормальный датафрейм для дальнейшей роботы с ним?

Comment: Возможно, но я точно не знаю, как вас проинструктировать. Попробуйте выделить и скопировать из Excel весь столбец A, вставить в блокнот и сохранить как другой csv-файл (не заменяйте старый файл, чтоб не потерять случайно данные) — если я ничего не напутал, то экранирование уберётся и всё станет хорошо

Comment: Да, сработало. 
Спасибо большое!

Comment: Минус за оформление поста: надо было пример csv вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы прочитать поломанный CSV файл с излишним обрамляющим квотированием:

```
"col1,""col2"",col3"
"1,""2018-08-01"",1.11"
"2,""2018-08-02"",2.22"
"3,""2018-08-03"",3.33"
```

можно избавиться от одиночных обрамляющих двойных кавычек и распарсить данные из переменной:

```
import io
import re
import pandas as pd

with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(re.sub(r'\"{1}([^"])', r'\1', data)), parse_dates=['col2'])
```

результат:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   col1       col2  col3
0     1 2018-08-01  1.11
1     2 2018-08-02  2.22
2     3 2018-08-03  3.33

In [20]: df.dtypes
Out[20]:
col1             int64
col2    datetime64[ns]
col3           float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так делал:

```
df = pd.read_csv('имя файла.csv', sep=';', quotechar="*", escapechar='"', header=0, names =['fixed acidity',"volatile acidity","citric acid","residual sugar",
                          "chlorides","free sulfur dioxide","total sulfur dioxide","density","pH","sulphates","alcohol","quality"])
```

Здесь нужно перечислить названия колонок, которые в таблице... Надеюсь, Вы поняли, что нужно сделать исходя из моего примера.